# How should I pass property values from View to Model in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I have three classes,
first:

```
public class Setting
```

which has properties:

```
string ID, string Value; (implements INotifyPropertyChanged on Value)
```

Second:

```
public class SettingCollection
```

which is a:

```
ObservableCollection<Setting>
```

Third:

```
public class SimObject
```

which has properties:

```
string ID, SettingsCollection Settings;
```

I have a View: 
SettingsDisplay.xaml
which has dependency property:

```
SettingsCollection SimObjSettings;
```

and displays the setting's ID and with its Value in a TextBox inside an ItemsContainer.

My MainWindow ViewModel has a SimObject Jeff; and in the View I have

```
<local:SettingsDisplay SimObjSettings="{Binding Jeff.Settings}"/>
```

This all works fine.

I need to know when a `Setting` `Value` changes and when that happens I need to know the SimObject ID the `Setting` belongs to so that I can call a method that sends an event with the `Setting` `ID`, `Value` and  the `SimObject` `ID`. (e.g. `SendEvent(settingID, settingValue, targetObject)`)

Obviously `Setting`'s and `SettingCollection`'s have no knowledge of what `SimObject` they belong to.

The way I've tried to do this is in the `Setting` class call `SendEvent` in the Value property's Setter.

I'm struggling to find a suitable way to pass the `SimObject`'s `ID` down the chain to the `Setting`'s class, I also don't think this is a good solution.

What is the best way to acheive what I'm trying to do?

Comment: "I need to send live Value changes to another system" - to you mean to another application? can you specify this pls.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for some kind of event messaging system. I'd recommend you check out Prism's [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122(v=pandp.20).aspx) or MVVM Light's [Messenger](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/). Then you can broadcast the change whenever a value changes, and anything that cares about listening for those changes can subscribe to receive those event messages. I have a brief summary of [event systems in MVVM](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/communication-between-viewmodels-with-mvvm/) on my blog if you're interested.

Comment: @blindmeis sorry to clarify, I have an unmanaged DLL which I communicate with through a CLR interface.

Comment: @Rachel i'm not sure how those event messaging systems would help in my case, what would I subscribe to?

Comment: @user13070 Your objects that change would publish an event message saying they changed. Anything that cares to be notified would subscribe to receive that kind of messages. Both libraries I linked have an object that handles the event messages (`EventAggregator` or `Messenger`), and you'd use that object to publish or subscribe to messages

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. Is there a simplified version that doesn't involve dissecting Prism or MVVMLight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by giving all `Setting`'s a `SimObject` property, which was the setting's SimObject owner, and creating an event handler `delegate void SettingHandler(string settingID, string settingValue, string targetObj);`
in `SimObject` : `public event SettingHandler SettingChanged;`

```
public void RaiseSettingChangedEvent(string settingId, string settingValue, string targetObj)
{
    if (SettingChanged != null)
    {
        SettingChanged(settingId, settingValue, targetObj);
    }
}
```

In `Setting` on the `string Value` Setter:

```
set
{
   _value = value;
   RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
   SimObject.RaiseSettingChangedEvent(ID, Value, SimObject.Settings["UID"].Value);
}
```

Then in `SettingsDisplay` I created a SelectedPropertyChangedCallback which adds the `ParameterChanged` event to the `SimObject` and also contains the `SettingChanged` method:

```
public void SettingChanged(string settingID, string settingValue, string targetObj)
{
    Framework.GetBusinessDelegate().SendEvent(settingID, settingValue, targetObj);
}
```

Don't know how to add syntax highlighting to make this answer clearer.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this, but obviously all of them involve someone observing the `SettingsCollection` *and* dynamically attaching/detaching `PropertyChanged` handlers to all items inside it (at least that's what your requirements sound to me).

I would argue that if all you want is unconditional live updetes you should not involve the Views and ViewModels at all in this. Simply write an implementation of something like this:

```
interface ISimObjLiveUpdateService
{
    void StartObserving(SimObject o);
    bool IsObserving(SimObject o);
    bool StopObserving(SimObject o);
}
```

The actual implementation would hook up to observe `o.SettingsCollection` and all items in it. Before you display a `SimObject` you `StartObserving` it, and when the view is closed you `StopObserving` it.

Comment: Is there a name for the type of solution you've provided so that I can research it, as I don't fully understand the step from what you've provided to monitoring Value changes of SimObject settings from an implementation of the interface. But this sounds like exactly what I need, thank you.

Comment: It's called the "observer pattern", but that's really in the most general sense. C#'s events model this pattern.